# How to test @RestController when all of the mapping return with ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, testing, spring-restcontroller

I need to do unit testing on a @RestController where every method returns with a ResponseEntity.
I have a CRUD repository to use but I don't know how can I test it with the ResponseEntities.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/events")
public class EventController {
    @Autowired
    private EventRepository eventRepository;

    @GetMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Event>> getAll() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(eventRepository.findAll());
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Event> get(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        Optional<Event> event= eventRepository.findById(id);
        if (event.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(event.get());
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<Event> post(@RequestBody Event event) {
        EventsavedEvent = eventRepository.save(event);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(savedEvent);
    }
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

So far so good , I can help you .

First of all, you must add unit test dependency. 
After that you must examine below code.
Below code only consist for create.
Good luck.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class EventControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

        @Test
        public void testCreateEvent() {
            Event event = new Event(); // Your entity
            event.setEventName("Test"); // Your entity attributes

            URI location = testRestTemplate.postForLocation("http://localhost:8080/events", event);

            Event event2 = testRestTemplate.getForObject(location, Event.class);

            MatcherAssert.assertThat(event2.getEventName(), Matchers.equalTo(event.getEventName()));


        }
```

}